# Как поэтапно создать скрипт рейтинга?

Tags: javascript, jquery

В общем сверстал красивую форму рейтинга, работает без JS, но мне надо оживить ее:

```css
    .rating-form {

      padding-top: 20px

    }

    .rating-form:after {

      display: table;

      clear: both;

      content: ""

    }

    .rating-form .total-vote {

      margin-bottom: 20px;

      color: #ccc

    }

    .rating {

      margin-bottom: 10px;

      display: -ms-flexbox;

      display: -webkit-flex;

      display: flex;

      -webkit-flex-direction: row-reverse;

      -ms-flex-direction: row-reverse;

      flex-direction: row-reverse;

      -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;

      -ms-flex-pack: end;

      justify-content: flex-end

    }

    .rating:after {

      display: table;

      clear: both;

      content: ""

    }

    .rating label,

    .rating>input:checked ~ label {

      width: 16px;

      height: 16px;

      overflow: hidden;

      white-space: nowrap;

      cursor: pointer;

      text-indent: -9999px

    }

    .rating:not(:checked)>label,

    .rating>input:checked ~ label,

    .rating:not(:checked)>label:hover,

    .rating>input:checked+label:hover,

    .rating>input:checked+label:hover ~ label,

    .rating>label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label,

    .rating:not(:checked)>label:hover ~ label {

      background: url("http://artlenk.ru/project/star.png") no-repeat

    }

    .rating:not(:checked)>input {

      position: absolute;

      top: -9999px;

      clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0)

    }

    .rating:not(:checked)>label {

      background-position: 0 -16px

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/master/src/js.cookie.js"></script>


<form action="#" class="rating-form">
  <div class="rating">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5">
    <label for="star5" title="5">5</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4">
    <label for="star4" title="4">4</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3">
    <label for="star3" title="3">3</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2">
    <label for="star2" title="2">2</label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1">
    <label for="star1" title="1">1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="total-vote"><span class="count">2</span> голоса</div>
</form>
```

1. При клике на звезду, берется значение из value и учитывается 1 клик, которой заносится в сессию.
2. Клик, который был совершен на звезду выводится на экран в .count (сессия не допускает скрипту считает еще клики одного пользователя).
3. Если другой пользователь (или с другого браузера) поставит оценку (совершив клик по звезде), снова повторяются первые два пункта и суммируется голоса, выводятся на экран в тег с классом .count

вот это я понимаю, но не могу никак написать эти действия в скрипт.

Comment: Если есть возможность, сделай пожалуйста в коде, чтобы можно было запустить и посмотреть

Comment: сделал и добавил нужные библиотеки.

Comment: Какую роль должен выполнять скрипт?

Comment: роль скрипта вывести текущую оценку и учесть новую оценку. Правда, я не знаю, JS может ли записывать куда-то действия одного пользователя, что бы учесть когда другой оставит оценку.

Comment: Текущую оценку лучше выводить при загрузке страницы, а при изменении рейтинга можно отправить запрос серверу

Comment: для js не принципиально иметь label и input одновременно, можно ообще на дивах, хтмл можно упростить, уменьшить его объем.

Comment: это понятно, но задача состоит, что бы при выключенном JS работало, вернее проявляла некую жизнь :)

Comment: alex-lenk я вижу и здесь и на toster токового ни чего не ответили

Comment: без php толку ноль будет , это обычный запрос и вывод в в цикле

Comment: бывает, ничего страшного, значит придется искать еще решения.

Comment: @alex-lenk ну как вы хотите отправить запрос на сервер, сохранив при этом значения рейтинга? Да никак, либо будите делать это моментально на ajax (с javascript), либо будете перенаправлять человека на страницу где серверный код уже добавит значения куда вам нужно, и перекинет обратно на страницу, где уже будет обновленные данные по рейтингу